# Bring Ball To A Stop

Tags: java, math, user-interface, methods, gravity

I have the following methods in my program which keep a ball continuously bouncing. I have tried modifying but can't seem to get the ball to stop at the bottom of my GUI. My main goal is to have the methods simulate as if you were bouncing a real ball.

```
private void updateDelta() {
        final int minimumMovement = 5;
        final int maxExtra = 10;
        deltaY = minimumMovement + (int) (Math.random() * maxExtra);
    }

    public void verticalBounce(Container container) {

        // controls vertical ball motion
        if (upDown) {
            y += deltaY;

            if (y >= getHeight()) {
                upDown = false;
                updateDelta();
            }
        } else {
            y += -deltaY;
            if (y <= 0) {
                upDown = true;
                updateDelta();
            }
        }

    }
```

UPDATE:

Ball bounces and stops at the bottom of the gui.

```
public void verticalBounce(Container container) {

    deltaY = deltaY - gravity;
    y = y + deltaY;

    if (y > getHeight()) {
        y = getHeight(); // reset location
        deltaY = (int) (deltaY * -0.9); // slows down ball
    }

}
```

Comment: So what happens when the ball hits the bottom?

Comment: whenever I click on the GUI the ball will go upwards to the top of the window and then bounce down and then up again. each bounce off the wall either speeds it up or slows down.

Comment: @NPE That's the line of code `if (y <- 0)` detecting the bottom and changing the direction flag, `upDown`.

Comment: @LeeMeador I made an update. Maybe you could take a look and let me know what you think

Comment: Two things: 1) `if (y > top) y = top - (y - top)` and `if (y < bottom) y = bottom + (bottom - y)` will keep ball from passing top and bottom. Remember to set top and bottom so the full image of the ball doesn't go off the graphics area. (If the ball is a circle of radius 5 drawn at height=y ... set bottom to 5 so the whole circle shows all the time. And set top to maxY - 5 for the same reason.)

Comment: Oh ... and maybe 90% is too much loss in the bounce. Or too little. Try 95% and 85% and see what looks good.

Answer (score 2):

None of that code looks correct. You need to implement the equation(s) of rectilinear motion:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_motion

The one you need is `s = ut + 0.5 * a * t * t`, where

```
s = distance
u = an initial velocity - regard as the speed at which it hits the ground 
a = acceleration due to gravity (you can probably have this pretty arbitrary)
t = time
```

You reverse the sign of `a` on the way up.

To simulate lossy bouncing, reduce `u` by taking a certain factor of energy E out of the system:

`new_u * new_u = (1 - E)u * u`.

(This comes from the formula for the *kinetic energy* of a moving body).

I can see from your question that you are capable of implementing this, so I won't provide code; just the physics.

Comment: @NPE perhaps, but the call to `random` confuses me.

Comment: To do a bouncing ball graphic you need the location at each time interval/loop. I think that's your `s`. The equations need to be in a form such that you can take `s` and calculate `s'` (the next location).

Comment: No, the way I've formulated it is that s is the absolute distance; more stable to do it that way in floating point. I like your answer though, hence +1

Answer (score 2):

First, a bouncing ball doesn't have a random element in it. Its all determined by the forces acting on the ball and the speed and direction of the ball. If you add a little randomness, it may make it look a little more realistic because of things like wind and unbalance in the ball but its very little.

To program it, assume the ball gets shot up from the ground at some speed. You need to store:

- `Y` = location in units above the ground. Start at 0.
- `deltaY` = speed in units per time interval. Negative is down. Positive is up. Start at 10.
- `gravity` = acceleration in units of change per time interval. Gravity is always negative and constant. Start with -2 and try some values.

Unless you want the ball to disappear off the screen as it reaches the top of the bounce, you will need to select a ceiling height. Say 100. (Which is best chosen to match your graphics area's height, though.)

So for every time interval/tick/loop you do the following:

- Adjust for gravity by subtracting gravity from deltaY. (If the ball is moving down it will move faster. If its moving up, it will move slower.)
- Move the ball by adding deltaY to Y.

Then you have to check: Did the ball hit the ground or the ceiling? Is Y greater than the ceiling value or less than the ground one (0).

If so, you have to bounce it by:

- Move Y such that if it was X past the boundary (ground/ceiling) it becomes X within the boundary. (If Y = 110 and ceiling = 100, set Y to 90. If Y = -5, set it to +5.)
- Negate deltaY. In a bounce the direction reverses. (deltaY = -deltaY)
- Reduce deltaY by a percentage. Some energy is lost in the bounce so speed is slower after a bounce. (deltaY = deltaY * 0.90 or some other amount) @Bathsheba calls that removing energy from the system.

That's all there is to it. You have to fiddle with the numbers to make it take off at a reasonable speed. You have to adjust the time interval. You don't have to match real life. Just do what looks good.

As time goes by, the speed will reduce to 0.

(And despite what I said before, adding or subtracting a small random amount actually looks kind of cool.)

Comment: been playing around with your suggestion but can't seem to stop the ball

Answer (score 0):

Your ball is bouncing randomly instead of slowly decreasing in velocity. You need to lower your velocity every bounce until the velocity is under minimumMovement then make the velocity 0 and stop bouncing.